# how to make edittable table using js or jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

## i want to create its content edittable but only first row is editing.

### this is not working for other row instead of first any way to do it reply fast

```
<script>
$("#edit_foo").click(function(){
   $("#text1").hide(); 
   $("#text2").hide();
   $("#text3").hide();
   $("#text4").hide();
});
</script>
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <tr>
        <th>Website</th>
        <th>phone</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Facebook_URL</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
                <?php foreach($footertables as $post)
{
?>
    <tr>
        <td><span id="text1"><?php echo $post->website?></span><input type="text" value="<?php echo $post->website?>" class="form-control"/></td>
        <td><span id="text2"><?php echo $post->phone?></span><input type="text" value="<?php echo $post->phone?>" class="form-control"/></td>
        <td><span id="text3"><?php echo $post->Email?></span><input type="text" value="<?php echo $post->Email?>" class="form-control"/></td>
        <td><span id="text4"><?php echo $post->facebook?></span><input type="text" value="<?php echo $post->facebook?>" class="form-control"/></td>
        <td><a href="#" class='btn btn-primary' id="edit_foo"><span>&#x270D;</span>Edit</a> <a href="<?php echo base_url().'dashboard_controller/deletefooter/'.$post->id;?>" class='btn btn-danger delete'><span>&#9003;</span> Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
                <?php
}
?>
    </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Maybe you need to give a unique name using for example a counter for these id for each loop item ( foreach($footertables as $post))

Comment: can you give me any example

Answer (score 0):

Can You please implement this :
https://editor.datatables.net/examples/inline-editing/simple

Comment: i see this but this is not solving my problem.after editing i have to save the data in db using model and contoller

Comment: @jawaharsharma If you have not already too deep in your current and custom sollution, I would advise to use editable data table and Yes, It have its server side code example as well to save data in db that can easily integrated with codeigniter.